# Time-partitions of sample size

Tags: probability, variance, sampling, mean, sample-size

I am struggling with explain something I read in a Whitepaper. The essence is as follows.

Let's begin with a random variable $X$ defined as number of events in an hours. Further, we assume that $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Now based a sample survey (or historical hourly records) one can reasonably approximate $\mu$ and $\sigma$ as sample mean as variance. So this part is pretty straightforward.

After this the authors claimed that, suppose $\widehat{X}$ is the R.V. representing the number of event in the first 30 min of every hour, then $\widehat{X}\sim\mathcal{N}(\widehat{\mu},\widehat{\sigma}^2)$ where

$\widehat{\mu} = \delta \mu$   and

$\widehat{\sigma} = \frac{\delta}{\sqrt{\delta^2 + (1-\delta)^2}}\sigma$

where $\delta = 0.5$. I can see the scaling of $\mu$ (expected number of events in 30min period would be about half of those in an hour). But can someone help me under scaling of the variance (standard deviation)

Maybe we can begin by assuming that it any 30min interval, and not just the first 30min of every hour.

Comment: Forget that paper! Number of events cannot be negative ... so they cannot be normally distributed.

Comment: I can see that. Just for argument sake let's forget the underlying distribution. Can I estimate the sample moments of $\widehat{X}$ from those of $X$? I guess thats what I struggling with. I am really concerned about the underlying distribution.

Comment: You might want to consider using the Poisson distribution.